# PHP StdClass - access fields as ->field or ->{'field'}

Tags: php, field, stdclass

I'm working on this PHP code collaboration and it seems that some people access PHP StdClass fields like this

```
$body->head
```

and others like

```
$body->{'head'}
```

As far as I can tell these are equivalent. Are they? Does it matter which is used? Which way would you prefer? Any quirks to look out for here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are equivalent. You only need the second version if you want to use abhorrent attribute names like:

```
$data->{'what * the ! thing'}
```

This sometimes happens if you convert pure data arrays into objects.

But there is also the double quotes version, which makes a bit more sense when you actually need variable attribute names (basically variable variables for objects):

```
$data->{"attr$index"}
```

Comment: Yep. Just avoid `$body->{'head'}` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I need to create class with abnormal property names like this {'field-name'}.

```
class myclass
{
    public {'field-name-with-minus-sign'} = "something";
}
```

Id doesnt work. Why? I dont want to use something like this:

```
$myclass = new stdClass();
$myclass->{'dumb-property-name'}
```

because i have a lot of properties like this.